# Mouse (in VirtualBox) scrolls horizontally

Tags: mouse, virtualbox, mouse-scroll

(the context of this question is within virtualbox, but AFAIK it shouldn't really be different)

I have a Microsoft 5-button mouse plugged in, to which scrolling scrolls horizontally. Any ideas?

`xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox USB Tablet                     id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse           id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ (unnamed)                                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

EDIT: This question is a pretty close duplicate of [My mouse wheel has stopped scrolling up and down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17414/my-mouse-wheel-has-stopped-scrolling-up-and-down). Could someone possibly mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: If you use `xev` and scroll the mouse wheel over its window, are `button 4` and `button 5` events generated, or are they `button 6` and `button 7`?

Comment: it's 6 and 7. I fixed it with http://askubuntu.com/questions/17414/my-mouse-wheel-has-stopped-scrolling-up-and-down

Comment: The answer here is exactly what fixed it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533299/how-to-disable-horizontal-scrolling-within-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-guest-windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with this: [My mouse wheel has stopped scrolling up and down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17414/my-mouse-wheel-has-stopped-scrolling-up-and-down)

I don't know what caused the problem, but those tools helped diagnose and fix it.